# Permissions for a shared webserver

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, webserver

My university gives us access to servers on which we each have an `user1/html/` folder within which we are able to put any static website files. I have placed my entire website here, but I also have some "unlisted" pages on my website (ex. `example.com/209219013.html`) that I don't wan't people to be able to find without going directly to that url.

However, as it is right now, people can go from their home folder (lets say `user2/`) and just do `cd ../user1/html/` and they can see the directory listing of all files (including `209219013.html`) within the hosting server (which allows them to then go directly to `example.com/209219013.html`). Is there any way to change the permissions such that I can rwe my files, anyone who tries to list the directory from the server gets blocked, and anyone who goes in from a browser (or publically) is able to see the contents?

Answer (score 0):

The university has allowed listing the directory contents for all of the user1/html maps. You can manipulate what visitors can see with the `.htaccess` file for each individual map of directory in 'your' tree. See documentation [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html)

Comment: I don't think that .htaccess concerns useres that are logged in on the web-server from using cd and ls to explore other users directories - which was what OP was asking, I think.

Comment: I may have misinterpreted the question: I assumed OP (user1) wanted to keep user2 from going to `example.com/~user1/209219013.html`. So, OP will have to take a look at directory permissions, and/or change the group of his ~user1/html directory in such a way that Apache (et al) can still read but user2 cannot. `chgrp www-data ~user1/html` and `chmod 750 ~user1/html`?

Comment: @SorenA is correct. I wanted *everyone* to be able to access sites from `example.com/~user1/209219013.html`. What I want to prevent is people from cding into the folder (cd ~/user1/html/) and being able to list the directory contents and read it as they wish. I assume this is just a permissions error that is fixable.

Comment: So, did the chgrp and chmod do the trick for you?